# Creating an advanced e-commerce website in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Okay, so, as the title suggests I'm supposed to create a rails app. - an e-commerce platform. I've done some background research and found a few useful gems like shoppe, spree. Specifications of my website are:

1. Searching using wide variety of options like price, company, title etc
2. Companies' accounts for uploading/updating products
3. Users' accounts for purchasing them
4. A staff panel (separate from companies' accounts) showing latest orders etc

What I want to ask is, is there anyone who has created some sort of a similar app in rails? Which gems are the most useful? With one gem, let's say shoppe, extending its functionality: is it going to be easy like adding companies accounts, user accounts and admin panel? Any general guidelines that you have?

Comment: You should take the opportunity to review the [Stack Overflow help file](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help) and familiarize yourself with the types of questions that are on topic for this site. Stack Overflow is not a discussion site, but rather, a place to ask and receive answers regarding specific technical issues. This isn't a place to ask for a free design consultation.

Comment: I searched Github explore and found a lot of Rails ecommerce platforms [link](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ecommerce+rails). I also know that [rails composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer) has an Ecommerce option.

Comment: this is really simple - use spree commerce. https://spreecommerce.com

Answer (score 1):

The book [Beginning Ruby on Rails E-commerce](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Ruby-Rails-E-Commerce-Professional/dp/1590597362) may be of help. It was published in 2006 so it's probably very outdated by now.

If you wait a while you could purchase the [second edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Ruby-Rails-E-Commerce-Second/dp/1484212916/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1457759737&sr=1-3&keywords=rails) which will be released on 30th March 2016.